# syspolicy_purge_history 3rd step runs forever on a cluster node?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL Server cluster.  On one of the nodes, the `syspolicy_purge_history` job runs forever on step 3.

I did stop and restart the job, however, again it is running forever at step 3.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you are not using Policy Management, you can disable that job.